# Why Web Service works on Oracle Database but I cannot see actual changes on the db?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle11g

Hope someone can help me!

I'm very new to web services and Oracle databases. I have a web service that worked for few years on an SQL Server database. Now I'm switching the whole to an Oracle database.

First of all I've migrated all the table schemas from the SQL Server to the Oracle with success. Then I adapted the code so that it works also with Oracle databases. At the moment the Web Service is working fine and it says that all data have been saved on the Oracle db, but when I open it with Sql Developer and look inside the tables that should have been modified everything is unchanged. As I said I'm new to Web Services and Oracle dbs so I apologize in advance if my question is too stupid.

Any advice/suggestion is welcome!! 
Thanks!

Comment: One difference between Oracle and SQL Server is how they treat transactions. In the Oracle DB, nothing is committed until the client sends a `commit`. *However*, it was my belief that practically any tooling for Oracle that will work in the .NET sphere pretends that Oracle has [Auto-Commit mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/auto-commit-mode?view=sql-server-2017). Out of interest, what specific tools have you picked for the Oracle part of your data access code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I actually use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.